# Angular route issue while redirecting from external web server

Tags: angular, payment-gateway

I am developing a website by using Angular 5 with spring rest api. I have done PayU money payment gateway integration with my website for a customer payment.

HTML Code:

```
<div class='pm-button'>
      <button (click)="pay()">Pay now</button>
    </div>
    <form id="PayU" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" [(ngModel)] = "key" />
          <input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" [(ngModel)] = "hash"/>
          <input type="hidden" id="txnid" name="txnid" [(ngModel)] = "txnid" />
          <input type="hidden" id="productinfo" name="productinfo" [(ngModel)] = "productinfo"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="surl" name="surl" [(ngModel)] = "surl" />
          <input type="hidden" name="furl" name="furl" [(ngModel)] = "furl" />
          <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname" [(ngModel)] = "firstname" />
          <input type="hidden" name="phone" [(ngModel)] = "phone" />
          <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" [(ngModel)] = "email" />
          <input  type="hidden"  id="payuAmount" name="amount" [(ngModel)] = "amount" />
          <input  type="hidden"  id="service_provider" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa"/>
        </form>
```

Typescript code:

```
(<HTMLFormElement> document.getElementById('PayU')).submit();
```

After payment is done, payu money redirects the url to http://localhost:4300/customer-home/confirmation (I am passing as part of the initial request) with the parameters as HTTP Post. I have configured angular route for the above path but I am getting 404. I can understand that the url redirected from payu money as HTTP POST with the parameter. Is there anyway to handle the HTTP post request in angular 5 since angular will try to load the template through HTTP GET.

Please could you provide me any pointer and let me know if you need any additional details.

Thanks,
Nanda

Comment: Are you saying you want to know if an Angular application can handle a POST request?

Comment: Thanks Richards for looking into this . Yes. Also I want to know how can I handle it.

Comment: Angular is a client side framework, so no it cannot handle POST requests. Have your webserver (nginx/node.js) handle that POST request, and redirect the user to a confirmation page if needed

Comment: will handle it in server side. Thanks